# How to access Azure Key Vault (AKV) from Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) using Managed Identities

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-aks, azure-managed-identity

We have some dotnet Core App Services running on Azure and using Azure key Vault with Managed Identities.

Planning to deploy these dotnet core services to azure kubernetes but I haven't found any relevant document/support to use AKV with Kubernetes Services. Any Guidance or references

Answer (score 4):

There are a couple of options to access KV from AKS:

- [Use Azure Key Vault with FlexVol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/developer-best-practices-pod-security#use-azure-key-vault-with-flexvol) ([deprecated](https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-keyvault-flexvol). continue to use this for kubernetes version 1.15)

  > With Key Vault, you store and regularly rotate secrets such as credentials, storage account keys, or certificates. You can integrate Azure Key Vault with an AKS cluster using a FlexVolume. The FlexVolume driver lets the AKS cluster natively retrieve credentials from Key Vault and securely provide them only to the requesting pod. Work with your cluster operator to deploy the Key Vault FlexVol driver onto the AKS nodes. You can use a pod managed identity to request access to Key Vault and retrieve the credentials you need through the FlexVolume driver.
  >
  > Azure Key Vault with FlexVol is intended for use with applications and services running on Linux pods and nodes.
- [Use Azure Key Vault Provider for Secrets Store CSI Driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-driver) (For kubernetes  1.16+)

  > The Azure Key Vault Provider for Secrets Store CSI Driver allows for the integration of Azure Key Vault as a secrets store with a Kubernetes cluster via a [CSI volume](https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/).
- [Use Azure Active Directory pod-managed identities in Azure Kubernetes Service (Preview)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/use-azure-ad-pod-identity)

  > Azure Active Directory (Azure AD) pod-managed identities use Kubernetes primitives to associate managed identities for Azure resources and identities in Azure AD with pods. Administrators create identities and bindings as Kubernetes primitives that allow pods to access Azure resources that rely on Azure AD as an identity provider.

I found the pod identity approach easier as you don't need to change your code.

Comment: Looks like FlexVol is [deprecated](https://github.com/Azure/kubernetes-keyvault-flexvol).  The recommended replacement is the [Azure Key Vault Provider for Secrets Store CSI Driver](https://github.com/Azure/secrets-store-csi-driver-provider-azure).

Comment: [Pod managed identity](https://hovermind.com/azure-kubernetes-service/pod-identity#managed-pod-identity-add-on) is a good option, waiting for "pod managed identity V2"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like pod-managed identity is also deprecated.
Replaced by [Workload ID](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/workload-identity-overview?tabs=dotnet)

> This authentication method replaces pod-managed identity (preview), which integrates with the Kubernetes native capabilities to federate with any external identity providers on behalf of the application.