# Kubernetes Secrets per user

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, azure-aks

Each person who uses K8 has their own account for a NAS. If a pod needs to write to the NAS, it access the credentials from that user's secret. I do not want users to be able to see other people's secrets. I still want users to be able to create and use secrets for themselves. How can this be accomplished?

There should only be a small number of user defined namespaces. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/namespaces/
As such, having one namespace per user doesn't seem like a good solution. Even if I did implement it this way, the admin would need to set a ClusterRole for each user to only allow them to only access their own namespace.

Perhaps a secret manager has this functionality?

Comment: SO is for programming questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve the goal of allowing each user to create and use their own secrets in Kubernetes (K8s) for accessing a NAS, while preventing them from seeing other users' secrets and without creating a namespace for each user, you can use a combination of Role-Based Access Control (RBAC) and a secret management tool.

**Approach 1**

For each user, *create a Role and a RoleBinding in the shared namespace*. This Role should have permissions that only allow the user to read, create, and manage their own secrets. You do this by setting the `resourceNames` field in the Role definition to specific secret names that the user is allowed to access.

Example Role definition:

```yaml
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: shared-namespace
  name: user-specific-role
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["secrets"]
  resourceNames: ["user1-secret"]
  verbs: ["get", "list", "create", "update", "patch", "delete"]
```

Using RoleBindings, associate each user with their specific Role. This ensures that they can only interact with the secrets allowed by their Role.

Example RoleBinding:

```yaml
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: user-specific-rolebinding
  namespace: shared-namespace
subjects:
- kind: User
  name: user1
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: user-specific-role
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

[image]

**Approach 2:**

*Using a Secret Management Tool* such as [Azure Key vault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/quick-create-portal)

Create your KV
[image]

Go to [secrets](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-portal)-> Generate your own creds manually or import certificate-> choose accordingly. Here I am using manual method. Enter a unique name for the secret. For instance, use a naming convention like `nas-credential-username` where `username` is the name of the user the credential belongs to. Enter the NAS credential. This could be a token, a password, or any other form of credentials required for NAS access. Set activation dates, expiration dates, and other properties as needed. Repeat the process of adding a secret for each user, ensuring each secret has a unique name that can be easily associated with the respective user.
[image]

After adding all the secrets, review them to ensure they are correctly configured. You can click on each secret in the Key Vault to view its details. By default, only the Key Vault administrator will have access. Later, you can set specific access policies for each user or application that needs to retrieve these secrets in the access configuration.
[image]
When it comes time to use these secrets (e.g., in a Kubernetes pod or any application), you will need to authenticate to Azure to retrieve the secret value. The specific steps will depend on your application’s architecture and the environment where it's running. To upgrade an existing AKS cluster with Azure Key Vault Provider for Secrets Store CSI Driver capability you can follow the below [method](https://shailender-choudhary.medium.com/access-secrets-from-azure-key-vault-in-azure-kubernetes-service-e8efffe49427)

```
az aks enable-addons --addons azure-keyvault-secrets-provider --name <yourclustername> --resource-group <yourRG>
```

[image]
you can verify the same by listing all pods that have the `secrets-store-csi-driver` and `secrets-store-provider-azure` labels in the kube-system namespace as below

```
kubectl get pods -n kube-system -l 'app in (secrets-store-csi-driver,secrets-store-provider-azure)'
```

[image]

Then go to your respective VMSS and enable managed identities.
[image]

Create your secretproviderclass
[image]

[image]

Finally, you can mount the volume utilizing CSI and referencing your Secret Provider Class created above.

Both approaches have their pros and cons. Kubernetes RBAC is native and doesn't require additional tools, but it can be complex to manage as the number of users grows. A dedicated secret management tool offers more features and scalability but adds complexity and potentially cost to your infrastructure.

**Reference Document**-

[MS Doc- create keyvault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/general/quick-create-portal)

[MS Doc- Set and Retrieve secrets from Keyvault](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/key-vault/secrets/quick-create-portal)

[MS Doc- Upgrade an existing AKS cluster with Azure Key Vault provider for Secrets.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/csi-secrets-store-driver)

[Steps to Access Secrets from Azure Key Vault in Azure Kubernetes Service](https://shailender-choudhary.medium.com/access-secrets-from-azure-key-vault-in-azure-kubernetes-service-e8efffe49427)

[MS Doc- Create a Service Principal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/purview/create-service-principal-azure?wt.mc_id=searchAPI_azureportal_inproduct_rmskilling&sessionId=10162211f24f4313844cae45daa4dd28)

[Similar SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57940468/how-to-access-azure-key-vault-akv-from-azure-kubernetes-service-aks-using-ma#:%7E:text=You%20can%20integrate%20Azure%20Key%20Vault%20with%20an,Key%20Vault%20FlexVol%20driver%20onto%20the%20AKS%20nodes.)

Comment: This is excellent, thank you!